# Embedding Python in C++: Importing modules in python script works during one function call but not another

Tags: python, c++, python-import, importerror, python-embedding

I am writing a program that uses C++ as the data management backend and can call user-created python scripts to do various tasks. I am running into a problem though related to importing modules in the python script. I am passing values from C++ to python and performing Gaussian Process Regression from sklearn on those values, and simply returning the optimized model values or the GPR uncertainties back to C++. I have these two situations (model optimization and model validation) as two separate functions in the python script, as they will be called from different places from C++.

When I run the first function (model optimization), everything works great, and I get optimized hyper-parameters to return to C++ without incident. During the second function call though, the script fails, as it cannot import the GPR modules from sklearn (the same modules that the previous function successfully imported). I am not too familiar with embedding python into C++, so it's very possible that I'm simply missing something, or do not fully understand the rules. It isn't possible to provide a code from the C++ end that can be run by itself, so I will do my best to provide as much of the embedding code as I can. The python scripts below are shown in full. If you need more information please let me know, I'm happy to provide it. Thank you for any help you can give.

**C++: Main**

```
//other stuff

Py_Initialize();

//do more other stuff (embedding happens here)

Py_Finalize();

//do even more other stuff
```

**C++: Model Optimization**

```
PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append(\".\")");

pName = PyString_FromString(file.c_str());

pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
Py_DECREF(pName);

if (pModule != NULL) {
    pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, function.c_str());

    pArgs = PyTuple_New(size);

    PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 0, PyLong_FromLong(gp->getInnerFPSize()));
    PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 1, PyLong_FromLong(ntrain));

    k = 2;

    for(i = 0; i < trainingFP[modelNumber].size(); i++){
        for(j = 0; j < trainingFP[modelNumber][i].size(); j++){
            PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, k, 
            PyFloat_FromDouble(trainingFP[modelNumber][i][j]));
            k++;
        }           
    }
    for(i = 0; i < trainingForces[modelNumber].size(); i++){
        PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, k, 
        PyFloat_FromDouble(trainingForces[modelNumber][i]));
        k++;
    }
    Py_INCREF(pValue);
    pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);
    Py_DECREF(pArgs);

 }else {
    PyErr_Print();
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load \"%s\"\n", function.c_str());
    return 1;
}

Py_XDECREF(pFunc);
Py_DECREF(pModule);

optimalSigma = PyFloat_AsDouble(PyList_GetItem(pValue, 1));
optimalSigmaN = PyFloat_AsDouble(PyList_GetItem(pValue, 0));
optimalSigmaF = PyFloat_AsDouble(PyList_GetItem(pValue, 2));

Py_DECREF(pValue);
```

**C++: Model Validation**

```
PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append(\".\")");

pName = PyString_FromString(file.c_str());

pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
Py_DECREF(pName);

if (pModule != NULL) {
    pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, function.c_str());

    pArgs = PyTuple_New(size);

    PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 0, PyFloat_FromDouble(testFP[0].size()));
    PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 1, PyFloat_FromDouble(testFP.size()));
    PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 2, PyFloat_FromDouble(trainingFP.size()));
    PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 3, PyFloat_FromDouble(sigma));
    PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 4, PyFloat_FromDouble(sigmaN));
    PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 5, PyFloat_FromDouble(sigmaF));

    k = 6;

    for(i = 0; i < testFP.size(); i++){
        for(j = 0; j < testFP[i].size(); j++){
            PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, k, PyFloat_FromDouble(testFP[i][j]));
            k++;
        }           
    }
    for(i = 0; i < trainingFP.size(); i++){
        for(j = 0; j < trainingFP[i].size(); j++){
            PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, k, PyFloat_FromDouble(trainingFP[i][j]));
            k++;
        }           
    }
    for(i = 0; i < trainingFP.size(); i++){
        PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, k, PyFloat_FromDouble(trainingForces[i]));
        k++;
    }
    Py_INCREF(pValue);
    pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);
    Py_DECREF(pArgs);

 }else {
    PyErr_Print();
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load \"%s\"\n", function.c_str());
}

Py_XDECREF(pFunc);
Py_DECREF(pModule);

for(i = 0; i < testFP.size(); i++)
    prediction[i] = PyFloat_AsDouble(PyList_GetItem(pValue, i));

Py_DECREF(pValue);
```

**Python**

```
def GPR(*X):

from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import RBF, WhiteKernel
import re

#initialize local variables
counter = 0
sigma_l_initial = 1
sigma_n_initial = 1
sigma_f_initial = 2
innerFPSize = int(X[0])
ntrain = int(X[1])

optimized_hyperparameters = []
forces = []
fp = [] 
sigma_l_bounds = [.01,100]
sigma_n_bounds = [.001,.1]

fp.append([])
#pass values from c++ conversion tuple to local lists
for x in X:
    if counter > 1 and counter < 2 + innerFPSize * ntrain:
        fp[len(fp) - 1].append(x)
    elif counter >= 2 + innerFPSize * ntrain:
        forces.append(x)

    counter += 1

    if len(fp[len(fp) -1]) == innerFPSize:
        if len(fp) < ntrain:
            fp.append([])

#GPR routine
krbf = sigma_f_initial*RBF(length_scale=sigma_l_initial,length_scale_bounds=(sigma_l_bounds[0],sigma_l_bounds[1]))
noise_kernel = WhiteKernel(noise_level=sigma_n_initial,noise_level_bounds=(sigma_n_bounds[0],sigma_n_bounds[1]))

gp = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=krbf + noise_kernel,normalize_y=True,n_restarts_optimizer=25)
gp.fit(fp, forces)

#get optimized hyperparameters
rr = re.findall("[-+]?[.]?[\d]+(?:,\d\d\d)*[\.]?\d*(?:[eE][-+]?\d+)?", str(gp.kernel_))
optimized_hyperparameters.append(float(rr[-1]))
optimized_hyperparameters.append(float(rr[-2]))
optimized_hyperparameters.append(float(rr[0]))

return optimized_hyperparameters





def GPR_unc(*X):

try:
    from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
    from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import RBF, WhiteKernel
except:
    print 'THIS REFUSES TO WORK'

#initialize variables
uncertainty = []
testFP = []
trainingFP = []
trainingForces = []

innerFPSize = int(X[0])
testSize = int(X[1])
ntrain = int(X[2])
sigma = float(X[3])
sigma_n = float(X[4])
sigma_f = float(X[5])

counter = 0

setTrainFP = setTrainForces = False
setTestFP = True

testFP.append([])
trainingFP.append([])

#parse data from C++ arrays
for x in X:

    try:
        if counter > 5 and setTestFP == True:
            testFP[len(testFP) - 1].append(x)
        elif setTrainFP == True:
            trainingFP[len(trainingFP) - 1].append(x)
        elif setTrainForces == True:
            trainingForces.append(x)

        if counter > 5 and setTestFP == True:
            if len(testFP[len(testFP) -1]) == innerFPSize:
                if len(testFP) + 1 <= testSize:
                    testFP.append([])
                else:
                    setTestFP = False
                    setTrainFP = True                                   
        elif setTrainFP == True:
            if len(trainingFP[len(trainingFP) -1]) == innerFPSize:
                if(len(trainingFP)) + 1 <= ntrain:
                    trainingFP.append([])
                else:
                    setTrainFP = False
                    setTrainForces = True
        counter += 1
    except:
        print 'ERROR'

#perform static "optimization" of gpr kernel to get gpr object
krbf = sigma_f**2*RBF(length_scale=sigma,length_scale_bounds=(sigma,sigma))
noise_kernel = WhiteKernel(noise_level=sigma_n,noise_level_bounds=(sigma_n,sigma_n))
gp = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=krbf + noise_kernel,normalize_y=True, optimizer=None)
gp.fit(trainingFP, trainingForces)

#get uncertanties on test set
val,std=gp.predict(testFP,return_std=True)

#ensure that the uncertainty is loaded into a float list in order to be sent back to c++
for x in std:
    uncertainty.append(float(x))
for x in std:
    uncertainty.append(float(x) * float(x))

return uncertainty
```

The python script fails when attempting to import the modules from the GPR_unc function (second function from the python code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the model validation function, the python tuple:

```
pArgs = PyTuple_New(size);
```

had an incorrect size passed to it compared to what was being appended to it. The crash ended up being a simple "writing past the end of the array without resizing it".